# Primary key and foreign key's insertion

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, constraints

Suppose I have two table's Department and Employees
Department DepID is Primarykey ,and DepID is foreign key in Employee table.I want to insert the data from Asp.Net application in both tables in one time.How can I get the primary key value DepID from Departments to insert into foreign key Employee table?

Comment: use scope_identity() method..it will return id of last inserted row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to run a "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()" query to get the last ID just after the insertion?